# I lost my data in other table when I rolled back my migrations in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a `users` table that has a one-to-one relationship with a `school_members` table. I was messing around and rolled back my single last migration and migrated it back right after here's the file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('jwtv')->default(null)->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('jwtv')->default('')->change();
        });
    }
};
```

now mind you my `users` table and `school_members` table are related via user id not `jwtv`, but this action caused me to lose data over at my `school_members` table and NOT the `users` table, those data were fine. also there's many to one relationship between `roles` and `users` table via roles id, but roles table are fine. lastly this I do have `onDelete('cascade')` for the one-to-one relationship.

My goal is trying to understand this so it doesn't happen to me in the future.

Comment: What is it you want us to help you with? Preventing such things from happening in the future or restoring the 'lost' data? If it is the latter, then we can't help you there. Do you have a backup of the data/table from before you did the rollback?

Comment: Preventing such things from happening in the future! just looking for an explanation as I stated in the end. sorry for the confusion I'm updating the question

Comment: Put you APP_ENV in production